# Storing numbers from a file to an array

Tags: c, arrays, loops

I am coding an algorithm that takes a file from the command prompt and stock its numbers into an array.

The file looks like this:

```
12 563 898 521
```

And here is the code:

```
// INCLUSION
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//  CODE

void howto(const char *) ;

int main(int k, const char *argv[])
{   if (k < 2) howto(*argv) ;
    int i = 0, array[2500] ;
    FILE * R = fopen(argv[1], "r") ;

    // pass file content to array
    if (! R) return 1 ;
    while (!feof(R)) {
        fscanf(R, "%d ", &array[i]) ;
        i++ ; }
    fclose(R) ;
    for(int x = 0 ; x < i ; x++ ) {
        printf("lol : %d\n", array[x]) ; }
    return 0 ; }

void howto(const char *P) {printf("Expected: %s <file to read>\n", P) ; }
```

The code run without warnings but has no result: it sorts of run forever.
I am guessing my issue comes to my while loop, but I have not been coding in C for a while and I have no idea why the syntax is not having the intended effect. 
Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: Please use an orthodox C layout style, preferably Allman or 1TBS.  Pico style is OK for Pico, but not for C.

Comment: Note that a trailing blank in a `scanf()`-family format string is awful if the input will ever be interactive.  Also, you should check that you don’t overflow the array.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler can you elaborate on the reason why I shouldn't use a blank in my fscanf?

Comment: @InTheMoodForNow You can start with the Wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style#Styles

Comment: See [Trailing blanks in `scanf()` format strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19499060/) for a good discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read manual page of `fscanf` & Check the return value. `man 3 fscanf` says

> These  functions  return the number of input items successfully
>   matched
>          and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in the
>          event of an early matching failure

Replace

```
while (!feof(R)) {
      fscanf(R, "%d ", &array[i]) ;
      i++ ; 
}
```

with

```
while (i < 2500 && fscanf(R, "%d ", &array[i]) == 1) { /*return 1 if read one item */
      i++ ;
}
```

Also read [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: I was sure it came from that while! Thank you so much for the in-depth answer to read too. Solved my issue and told me why I had it in the first place ;).